# Why does electrolysis require a base electrolyte instead of an acid electrolyte?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, voltage

I am in the process of using electrolysis to remove rust from some old tools. This is the process where you submerge the rusted item  in a bath along with a sacrificial piece of metal. You connect a 12V negative lead to the rusted item and the positive lead to the sacrificial piece. The bath is charged with a base.

My question is, why a base and not an acid bath? The reason I ask is because you can usually use an acid to remove rust. Wouldn't an acid work better? Also, can't you use an acid and switch the leads, making the rusted item connected to the positive?

The best understanding I can come up with is that the bath as a base contains an excess of electrons that prevent the electrons from being captured by the water molecules.